# Magento Url ReWrite Management Error ver. 1.6.2.0

Tags: mysql, magento

I am currently working on a Magento store (ver. 1.6.2.0) however when i click on the url re-write management i get a Magento error page, below is the information from the Magento error log.

So far i have tried the following

1. Restoring the Mage.php file
2. Restoring index.php
3. Refreshing indexes and clearing cache
4. Deleting all data in catalog_url_rewrite table and reindexing

```
2012-01-23T17:16:21+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1' in /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1350
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(432): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[42000]...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(661): Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[42000]...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1624): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(964): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_afterLoad(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 213, NULL)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 213, NULL)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(213)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(121): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product->initProduct(213, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#8 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(213, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#9 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(80): Mage::run('base', 'website')
#16 {main}
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me figure this out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you working on a clean magento install, or an upgrade from a previous version?

Comment: Hi Mike its an upgrade from a previous version, do you have any idea as to what this could be? i am going to try the Magento database repair tool to see if that clears things up. Appreciate your help people!

Comment: That's what I'd do. The upgrades seem to fail on occasion when upgrading multiple versions. DB repair works out most of the kinks. My problem is with the SQL Syntax Error. If that doesn't work we'll need to troubleshoot step by step in the trace above.

Comment: Hi Mike, tried the Magento DB repair but that didnt work. So looks like debugging the backtrace, however i am struggling. Any ideas?

Comment: I see a local override of Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php. I'd remove that (temporarily), then disable the ArtsOnIT plugin (temporarily). If that's still not the issue, then go step by step through the files listed in the trace and start adding a few lines like Mage::log("Here I am in the Catalog Model Resource Abstract load file") and watch in the logs where things start to break.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply, id followed what you said and it turns out the error was being thrown at the walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Array) stage. I did an email each time it went to the function and it turned out an old plugin that needed updating installed an attribute as the system. So it was looking for a model that didnt exist. 

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error was being thrown at the `walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Array)` stage. I did an email each time it went to the function and it turned out an old plugin that needed updating installed an attribute as the system. So it was looking for a model that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a 3rd party module for a client site where the suppliers can customize theirs 'products' schedule for some holiday.

Turns out they forgot to run save as admin.

To solve, before saving with something like:

```
$product->save()
```

Just set the current store to the admin one

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
```